# PIPX Install on MAC - Duplicate user/xxx/.local/bin in PATH

Tags: path, duplicates, zshrc, pipx

I have recently installed PIPX on MAC running Big Sur and ZSH shell.  During the install it prompted for the following to be added to the .zshrc file....

```
# Created by `pipx` on 2021-03-20 14:22:23
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin"

eval "$(register-python-argcomplete pipx)"
```

Running `echo $PATH` showed `/Users/xxxx/.local/bin` added to the end of my PATH variable.  However, when I close the terminal and open up a new session, running `echo $PATH` now shows the location duplicated at the end of the PATH `:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin`

Opening and closing new terminal sessions doesn't seem to create any more additions to PATH it just remains at these 2 entries....

I have run `typeset -U PATH path` to remove the duplicate but each time I open up new terminal sessions it just duplicates again.

Does anybody know how I can stop this from happening.....I would really like to keep my PATH variable as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following path to your `.zshrc` file :

```
export PATH="${PATH}:$(python3 -c 'import site; print(site.USER_BASE)')/bin"
```

Reference: [command not found: pipx]: https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx/issues/283